# style.display = "boxed"; isnt working

Tags: javascript, css, display

Trying to display a different image in a different location when clicked, this is an interval set to 10ms and when the value changes it should switch up the divs, one being none, and one boxed.

```
function test() {
  var x = document.getElementById('spc_02');
  var y = document.getElementById('purchase_01');
  if (rest === 0) {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "boxed";
  }
  if (rest === 1) {
    x.style.display = "boxed";
    y.style.display = "none";
  }
  var x = document.getElementById('spc_03');
  var y = document.getElementById('purchase_02');
  if (news === 0) {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "boxed";
  } if (news === 1) {
     x.style.display = "boxed";
     y.style.display = "none";
  }
 }
```

Comment: "boxed" doesn't appear to be a valid value for the display property. Did you mean "block"? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: display cannot be `"boxed"`, so it sets it to the default (I believe `inherit`) https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: Sorry, but what is display boxed? Don't you mean, display: "block" ?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: I'm quite sure "boxed" is a data type?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry that was very foolish of me, sorry for wasting your time ;-;

Comment: I'm pretty new to this anyway